# Can you add a Parenting group?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Can you add a group on Parenting? I always have questions about discipline, diet for children, travelling with young kids, etc., etc.

Comment: Shog pretty much addressed your specific request since a site already exists, but if there is ever a site you want to propose, check out [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).  You can propose new sites there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should check out https://parenting.stackexchange.com/:

> Parenting - Stack Exchange is for parents, grandparents, nannies and others who care for children.

Comment: Can we add "moderators" after nannies?

Comment: O.K., thanks. I did not know it was there because it was not at the footer of this page.

Comment: @Michael: yeah, we'll be adding a link to the full list of sites (and doing some other restyling there) pretty soon. FYI: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 5):

Parenting Stack Exchange, as Shog9 already mentioned, is the more suitable site for parenting questions, but since you mention diet for children and travelling with young kids, you might also be interested in checking out [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com) ([FAQ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq)) and [Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) ([FAQ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/faq)).

If your questions are more about travelling and diet than parenting, you might get better answers at the more specialised sites. That said, we can move questions between sites automatically, so don't lose *too much* time trying to decide what the more suitable site is. If your question is a good one, and there's a slightly better site for it, that's quite easy to fix.